# pxssh error 'could not synchronize with original prompt'

Tags: python-3.x

I have been getting the below error while using pxssh to get into remote servers to run unix commands ( like uptime )

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "./ssh_pxssh.py", line 33, in 
    login_remote(hostname, username, password)
  File "./ssh_pxssh.py", line 12, in login_remote
    if not s.login(hostname, username, password):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 278, in login

```
**raise ExceptionPxssh ('could not synchronize with original prompt')
```

pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: could not synchronize with original prompt**

Line 33 is where I call this function in main.

The function I am using is here :

```
def login_remote(hostname, username, password):
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.force_password = True
if not s.login(hostname, username, password, auto_prompt_reset=False):
    print("ssh to host :"+ host + " failed")
    print(str(s))
else:
    print("SSH to remote host " + hostname + " successfull")
    s.sendline('uptime')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.logout()
```

The error does not come each time I run the script. Rather it is intermittent. It comes 7 out of 10 times I run my script.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it by adding **sync_multiplier** argument to the login function.

```
s.login(hostname, username, password, sync_multiplier=5 auto_prompt_reset=False)
```

note that **sync_multiplier** is a communication timeout argument to perform successful synchronization. it tries to read prompt for at least **sync_multiplier** seconds.
Worst case performance for this method is **sync_multiplier** * 3 seconds.

I personally set sync_multiplier=2 but it depends on the communication speed on the system I work on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when pxssh tried to login on a very slow connection.
The pexpect lib apparently was fooled by the remote motd prompt.

This remote motd prompt contained a uname -svr prompt, which itself contained a # character inside.
Apparently, pexpect saw it like a prompt. From that point, the lib was not in line anymore with the ssh session.

The following workaround was working for me:
just remove the # char inside /var/run/motd.dynamic (debian), or in /var/run/motd (ubuntu).

Another solution is to ask ssh to no prompt the motd while logging in . But this is not working for me:
i added the following:
    PrintMotd no
in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
=> not working

Another workaround:
create a file in the home directory:
.hushlogin in the ~ directory